# Router limits blocks some sites from loading

Tags: wireless-networking, router

One of my wireless routers is acting up lately: After a few minutes of use, some of the sites become unavailable and some stay reachable.

I couldn't find a clear difference between the sites that are unreachable and the sites that stay available.

Another router on the same connection works fine.

I did a traceroute on some of the unreachable sites and it gets to my ISP but hangs there. Once I reconnect to the same router, the traceroute completes successfully.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please clarify "after a few minutes of use"; i.e. after restarting the router, or after connect to it & browsing?  If the latter, have you restarted the problem router?

Answer (score 0):

Check the firmware of the router.  I may be that the other router has newer firmware that prevents this issue from happening.

Comment: I forgot to mention it only happens from my computer. Other computers who connect to the same router don't have this issue.

Comment: @the-lights Have you checked your network card drivers, are they the newest version?